# Mongodb on plesk 12.5 and Ubuntu

Tags: plesk

I tried trying to install mongodb and php extension on my server with Ubuntu 14.04 and plesk 12.5 but without success of php extension. Anyone can help me with a simple tutorial on how to install mongodb driver and Mongo db php extension on my dedicated server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can look on [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)
DigitalOcean provides a detailed recipe: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

PHP MongoDB extension: [installation from PECL](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php)
[Forum AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765146/how-to-install-mongodb-php-extension-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

[Here](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213909265-How-to-enable-multiple-PHP-versions-in-Plesk-for-Linux) you can see how you're installing multiple versions of PHP and switching them in Plesk.
Mind that you install every PHP version independently with its own extensions.
In your case you need to add MongoDB extension to some (or all) PHP versions you work with.

Comment: Yes but the problem is the compatibility with plesk which uses different php version at same time for each site so how can I add php extension on plesk?

Comment: It doesn't matter what php version plesk uses. For each php version (separate folder) you add a separate php extension file and edit its php.ini. I.e. for PHP7 it will take its own extension, for PHP5 another.

Comment: Can u tell me how?

Comment: For telling more I need a question first :)  
[Here](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213909265-How-to-enable-multiple-PHP-versions-in-Plesk-for-Linux) you can see how you're installing multiple versions of PHP and switching them in Plesk.  
Mind that every PHP version you install independently with its own extensions.  
In your case you need to add MongoDB extension to some (or all) PHP versions you work with.
I'll update the answer

Comment: I have multiple versione but i'm using only one version for my site. the version 5.6.30. So after installing mongo with this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04) how can i add to php 5.6.30 in plesk the extension?

Comment: If you work with PECL (PHP extensions package manager), do: `$ sudo pecl install mongodb` and updating php.ini with `extension=mongodb.so`  Restart the webserver and check it by: `php -m`

Comment: I have this error after the first command

**compilation terminated.
make: *** [php_phongo.lo] Errore 1
ERROR: `make' failed**

Comment: plesk instructions for adding new extensions to each of the php versions they supply are here: https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/adding-custom-php-modules-in-plesk/